# xpages date picker compatible with ios devices

Tags: ios, xpages

In an xpage which will be used on mobile and pc, I have a date field.
I tried several things (see examples below), but the result is always the same: when the iOS user clicks on the icon next to the input field, the calender pops up, but disappears again...

It's nearly impossible to select a date on the iPhone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:bx="http://www.openntf.org/xsp/bootstrap"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
dojoParseOnLoad="true"
dojoTheme="true">
 ....
<xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                value="#{document1.crm_etabl_date}"
                defaultValue="#{javascript:@Today}">
                <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1">
                </xp:dateTimeHelper>
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                        dateStyle="short">
                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.crm_etabl_date}"
                id="date1" disableClientSideValidation="true"
                disableTheme="true">
                <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper2"
                    dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox">
                </xp:dateTimeHelper>

                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime type="date"
                        dateStyle="short">
                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
</xp:view>
```

**EDIT**
This inputText control was inside a table.
I removed it from the table, and then it's usable but it's not looking perfect...

Comment: What version and fix pack of Domino are you using? It works for me on 9.0.1 FP9.

Comment: We have 9.0.1 FP2

Comment: Upgrade to the latest fix pack then :-)

Comment: I can't decide about that + I'm not 100% sure it will work in my setup ...
Isn't there another way to let this work ?